# io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable in a+ mode

Tags: python, file

I have faced with strange problem. I have a pretty (but not really) textual file .txt with size 55,1 MB (55 082 716 bytes) that contains HTML-type markdown like this:

```
<div id="lesson-archive" class="container"><div id="primary" class="content-area match-height"><div class="lesson-excerpt content-container"><article><p>We hear about climate change pretty much every day now. We see pictures of floods, fires and heatwaves on TV news. Scientists have just announced that July was the hottest month ever recorded. The scientists are from the National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration (NOAA) in the USA. A spokesperson from NOAA said: "July is typically the world's warmest month of the year, but July 2021 outdid itself as the hottest July and hottest month ever." NOAA said Earth's land and ocean surface temperature in July was 0.93 degree Celsius higher than the 20th-century average of 15.8 degrees Celsius. The Northern Hemisphere was 1.54 degrees Celsius hotter than average.<br><br>
```

I would like to remove some elements by such regex: `[^a-zA-Z.,!?-—() ]`

Here is my code to solve this problem:

```
import re

with open('data.txt', 'a+') as f:
    data = f.read()
    edited_data = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z.,!?-—() ]', '', data)
    f.write(edited_data)
```

And that cause an error:

```
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable
```

There are some questions with similar problem but not in `a+` mode. Why did I get this error?

I use Python 3.8 on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot read the file with `read()` that is only available in default or `r` might want to do something like this

```py
import re

with open('data.txt') as f:
    data = f.read()
with open('data.txt', 'w') as f:
    edited_data = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z.,!?-—() ]',"", data)
    f.write(edited_data)
```

Comment: I have tried it but the file size is 105,2 MB now and there is no effect on the file content. There are still all special symbols.

Comment: @alyferryhalo the problem was that the `a` mode opens it in append mode so it appended the de-symbolised data into, but the `w` mode first cleans text file before writing into into it, it should work now